# Как AJAX'ом забирать результат

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

У меня есть вопрос по Ajax. На сервере есть функция, которая возвращает строку текста. Я отправляю туда входные данные, а на выходе хочу получить этот результат.

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
function Hello($name){
  return "Hello ".$name."!";
}
echo Hello($name);
```

Js:

```
var name = Petya;
var result;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data:({name:name}),
    beforesend: alert("SENDING: "),
    success: function(result){alert(result);}
 });    
  alert(result);
```

Последний `alert` ничего не выводит. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var name = "Petya";
var result = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data:({name:name}),
    beforesend: alert("SENDING: "),
    async: false,
    success: function(result){alert(result);}
  }).responseText; 
alert(result);
```

Только зачем вам 2 одинаковых алерта? (вопрос риторический)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Как раз то что искал.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `$.ajax` работает асинхронно. Соответственно. `alert(result)` сразу после вызова `$.ajax` почти наверное ничего не даст.

```
var name = "Petya";//кавычки не забываем
var result;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "script.php",
  data:({name:name}),
  beforesend: alert("SENDING: "),
  success: function(data){result = data;alert(result);}//глобальный result и локальный не путаем
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('script.php', {name: name}, function (data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Еще можно перед `script.php` добавить слеш, кто знает что у вас там за настройки сервера.