# Почему значение responseText равно undefined?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Судя по всему, вопрос возник вследствие недопонимания работы JavaScript, поэтому сильно не ругайте. Смысл следующий: делаю ajax запрос

```
var R = $.ajax({ <всякие там параметры> });
```

Когда я делаю `console.log(R);`, то вижу параметры объекта, в т.ч. `responseText`, в котором лежит правильное значение. Но когда пытаюсь получить значение вот так - `console.log(R.responseText);`, то получаю `undefined`. Аналогичная ситуация, при таком виде

```
var R = $.ajax({ <всякие там параметры> }).responseText;
```

`console.log(R);` - `undefined`. Если добавлять в параметр `success: function(r) { console.log(r); };`, то все отлично. Хотелось бы узнать, почему в первых случаях возвращается `undefined`.

Comment: @Алексей Ткаченко, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Прошу прощения - привык уже js, в особенности используя jQuery, читать и писать одной строчкой.

Comment: плохоя привычка

Comment: responseText приходит параметром в функцию обработчик

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы его (запрос) случайно не асинхронно отправляете? Мои познания в JS стремятся к нолю, но все же может быть в этом случае результат только в success-замыкание и подается? И вот [еще нашел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82784/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-ajax-%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82) - второй ответ.

Comment: Запрос отправляю не асинхронно. Не могу понять, почему при логировании объекта он мне говорит, что у него есть значение resposeText, а при обращении - его нет. Собственно, в лучшем ответе по ссылке есть то, что я пытался делать и получал все тот же undefined

Comment: Собственно, VioLet был прав(а). Еще раз внимательно проштудировал описание jQuery.ajax() и обнаружил, что по умолчанию запрос отправляется асинхронно. Собственно поэтому при обращении к св-ву объекта такового там пока что еще нет, т.к. js работает судя по всему быстрее моего канала или скрипта php. Выставление свойства async в false решило все мои проблемы.

З.Ы. @exec, Блин, жалко репы нет - минусанул бы ответ. Если Вы ищете resposeText в методах, то вы заблуждаетесь :) И то, что выводится таким путем это начинка самого объекта ajax, а не того, что возвращается.

Answer (score 2):

```
var g = $.post('/');
for(i in g) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

**Результат**

```
readyState
setRequestHeader
getAllResponseHeaders
getResponseHeader
overrideMimeType
abort
done
fail
progress
state
isResolved
isRejected
then
always
pipe
promise
success
error
complete
statusCode
```

Все эти параметры кроме `readyState` имеют тип `function`.

---

Посмотрите внимательно страницу документации [**jQuery.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) — где вы там увидели такое использование данного метода?

Comment: а где responseText ? Наверно он должен появиться при `statuscode==4` (подзабыл уже статускоды аякса- сильно не пинайте).

Comment: Непонятно это.