# Заполнение массива из ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, массивы

Вопрос в следующем: нужно заполнить массив результатами запроса ajax.
Я сделал так: объявил глобальную переменную


var arrMark = [];

```html
function CreateMarker(MarkerParams, Icon) {
  var results = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Libs/function.php",
    async: false,
    data: {
      GetIdLabel: "",
      SRN: MarkerParams.label
    },
    success: function (data) {
      return data;
    }
  }).responseText;
  arrMark[results] = marker;
}
```

results возвращает число! пробовал и в ручную проставлять.
если я вывожу console.log(arrMark.length) оно у меня равно 0.
В консоли отображаются 2 пустые скобки, но рядом стрелка, которая показывает какие данные должны находится в массиве, но массив пустой.
Подскажите, как мне заполнить массив значениями из ajax запроса.
CallBack тоже пробовал, история та же.[image: Результат в консоли]

Comment: что есть marker?

Comment: marker = new L.marker([MarkerParams.posX, MarkerParams.posY], { icon: CreateIcon(Icon) }).addTo(map)//создаем маркер
    .bindPopup('id метки: ' + MarkerParams.label + '<br> ' + MarkerParams.LabelLatsDateTime)//указываем текст для popup
Это маркер из библиотеки leafet.js

Значение маркера видно  в консоли, я выложил скрин

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/94935/212496